# Can I use semaphores between a java desktop application and a php website?

Tags: java, php, semaphore, shared-memory

I have a java program that spawns a web application. The ultimate purpose of this web application is to retrieve an authentication token that needs to be sent back to the java application.

I have learned about semaphores in my operating system classes and was wondering if semaphores/shared memory can be used between two different processes written in different programming languages. Excuse my naiveté but the concept is still fairly new to me and I have only used semaphores for programs written in the same language.

If this is possible, a sample would be greatly appreciated.

If not, what is my best option for sending a small amount of data between a PHP web app and a java desktop application (preferably not using a database)?

I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Which OS ? You could try to use named pipes or something like this

Comment: Windows 10 *added to post

Answer (score 1):

Semaphores are just counters with a binary semaphore being a 0,1 counter, or really just a lock.  Typically you use these in a process w/ threads, or between processes using an OS device like a pipe or shared memory or low level OS semaphore.

I think you can implement something similar w/ a shared service (webservice, rester, messaging, etc) that does the same thing -- automic incr/decr of a lock.  However you'll have to sort out the waiting semantics since typical semaphores may have a while() loop around it and wait until its free again.

I think you're better off thinking of a simpler approach?

Comment: Well I was thinking that I could create a new thread in my java program that gets blocked by the semaphore until the PHP process unblocks it once the data is in the shared memory